# What is the little doll on top of Tomoko's phone?

Tags: watamote

In [*WataMote*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WataMote_~No_Matter_How_I_Look_at_It,_It%E2%80%99s_You_Guys'_Fault_I%E2%80%99m_Not_Popular!~), Tomoko's phone appears to have a little figure on the top of it. It looks like a doll, with a kitty-face smile and an orange coat and antenna. In the ED sequence, it appears again, in both orange and blue.

[image: Tomoko's phone]
[image: The phone in the ED sequence]

Is this doll a reference to another series or Japanese pop culture? What does it mean?

Comment: It looks like a parody of Yaruo (やる夫), a popular ASCII Art meme character from the Japanese 2ch forum.

Comment: I think it's possibly just a weird mix of Yaruo and those little kawaii-doll things you can put on your phones...
But I'm not really the most experienced person so if it isn't Yaruo don't judge meh :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That guy is apparently from the Wii game [Opoona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opoona) where you play a character called "Opoona" that's short and has a number of facial expressions (and one of them has a ball over their head), though they don't always have such a sour look on their faces.

[image]

[image]

Some ascii art of Opoona with the Yaruo face that Krazer mentioned:

[image]